# Необходимо найти все натуральные числа, принадлежащие отрезку [223344556; 323456789] и имеющие ровно три нетривиальных делителя

Tags: python, перебор

На самом деле, рабочее решение на питоне есть, но его я не совсем понимаю. Формат вывода: для каждого числа нужно вывести само число и его наибольший нетривиальный делитель. Решение:

```
print(223344556**(1/4), 323456789**(1/4))
for i in range(123,135):
    ploho = True
    for j in range(2,i):
        if i % j == 0:
            ploho = False
            break
    if ploho:
        print(i**4, i**3)
```

Ответ:

```
260144641 2048383 
294499921 2248091
```

Я понимаю, почему у i^4  будет ровно 3 нетрив. делителя. Понимаю, почему i^3  - максимальный нетрив. делитель. Но разве не может быть такой ситуации, что в таком большом промежутке может быть число, которое имеет корень (число делителей нечётное), а также имеет ещё два нетрив. делителя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тривиальный делитель - это 1 или само число

В решение ищутся такие простые числа, чтобы `p^4 = z`, потому что тогда существует строго 3 нетривиальных делителя: `p, p^2, p^3`

предположим, что один из делителей числа `z` не простое число и не степень простого числа, т.е. `Y=a*b`, тогда `z = X*Y=X*(a*b)`, где X - это еще какой-то делитель и делителей будет уже минимум 6: `X, (a*b), a, b, (X*a), (X*b)`

Т.е. возможные варианты по кол-ву нетривиальных делителей:

- **0** нетривиальных делителей, если `z` - простое число
- **1** нетривиальный делитель, если `z = p^2` - квадрат простого числа
- **2** нетривиальных делителя, если `z=p^3` - куб простого числа
- **2** нетривиальных делителя, если произведение двух простых чисел `z=p1 * p2`
- **3** нетривиальных делителя, если `z=p^4` - 4 степень простого числа
- **4** нетривиальных делителя, если `z=p^5` - 5 степень простого числа
- **4** нетривиальных делителя, если произведение квадрата простого числа на другое простое число `z = p1 * p1 * p2`

остальные варианты имеют большее число нетривиальных делителей -

например произведение трех простых чисел `z = p1 * p2 * p3` даст уже 6 (!!!) нетривиальных делителей: `p1, p2, p3, p1 * p2, p1 * p3, p2 * p3`

а произведение простого числа на квадрат простого числа даст `z = p1 * p1 * p2` даст 4 нетривиальных делителя: `p1, p1 * p1, p2, p2 * p1`